# How to add random colors to fragment layout from main activity with button in main activity

Tags: android

I want to add random colors to fragment layout with the button on main activity. When I click on a button that is in main activity the color of fragment layout must be changed.

I tried with bundle, but it is not working.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
       bundle.putInt("key",getRandomColor());
       fragmentOne.setArguments(bundle);
     }
});

public int getRandomColor(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you said:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("color",getRandomColor());
            fragmentOne.setArguments(bundle);

        }
    });
```

and in your fragment class :

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_1, container, false);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relative_frag);
        int color = getArguments().getInt("color");
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);


        return view;
    }
```

and fragment layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative_frag"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Text"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its not working app crushes got null pointer exception... **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**
in this code:-
`int color = getArguments().getInt("color");`